# How to make sense of 6mo worth of weight loss data?

Tags: correlation, variance, mean, computational-statistics

-I have ~6mo of data that contains daily weight/caloric intake & #carbs/fats/proteins. I'm trying to figure out a way to make sense of the data. It's not a perfect experiment so there are other factors I should have considered and taken into account some sort of maintenance metabolic conditions (calories/macros to stay at a given weight) but I'm trying to derive something meaningful out of this data. I'm currently a junior/senior in EE with 1 stats course under my belt. My goal is to use what I've learned in class to understand my data better.

-What I've done so far: I've found the correlation coefficient between day n-1's calorie, carbs, fat or protein with day n - day n-1' weights, ie: how much a given macro or calorie amount correlates to the following day's change in weight.

-The correlation coefficient seems to make sense. The highest positive correlation was with carbs (larger % of diet as carbs, gain weight) and the only negative correlation was with fat (larger % of diet as fat, lose weight).

-Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you! (if suggestions are beyond the scope of an entry stats course please direct me to where I can learn more about said approach)

(I can attach my matlab code if anyone would like)

Comment: This seems to be backwards. You don't decide your hypothesis *after* you've done the experiment, you do that *before*. It is your hypothesis that guides everything from experimental design to making inference after you've collected data from the experiment. The question still remains, *what is your hypothesis?* Start from there instead of spitballing.

Comment: plot the data, (any combination of measures you think is relevant, eg carbs, weight by time, by day on the week &c..)  this will allow you get a better idea of the data as a whole rather than relying on individual statistics such as the ones you mentioned.

Comment: I plotted everything but it's hard to tell effectiveness of the 4 (calories, carbs etc) on weight loss. This is partially b/c I don't have data from maintenance... just weight loss unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

My read on this is that the day-to-day variance in your weight is likely to dominate any effect of the number of calories on the same or previous day. For example, how dehydrated you are. I think your data would be more meaningful by looking at weekly or monthly means. In that context, something like a regression of weight at end of week on this week's calories, previous week's calories and weight at start of week might be informative.

Comment: I tried weekly averages. The results are much different than my original method. This method suggests that protein has the biggest effect on weight gain... and that really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You have very little data, and it is probably very stable over time, which means you have even less data than you think. I suspect none of your results are statistically significant, which is why you find different answers when you change the method. To really test an day-to-day or week-to-week effect of calorie consumption on weight, I think you would need to follow many people for many years. With your data, I would focus more on data description (mean, variance), than trying to make causal inference.